# Powerapps - Dynamically adding columns (Input Text Boxes) to a table

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-datatable

I am trying to build a Power App that creates Input text boxes dynamically.

This is my data.

```
Category Name         Product 1       Product 2     Product 3  Product 4 
Marketing Center 1     1               1              2           2
Marketing Center 2     1               1              2           2
Marketing Center 3     1               1              2           2
Marketing Center 4     1               1              2           2
Marketing Center 5     1               1              2           2
```

Now, the Problem here is My Category Names and as well as Product columns increases over time.

How Can I build a User Input table dynamically to get the User Inputs - Something like this...and gives me the total of it...

```
Category Name         Product 1       Product 2     Product 3  Product 4   Total 
Marketing Center 1     1               1              2           2         6
Marketing Center 2     1               1              2           2         6
Marketing Center 3     1               1              2           2         6
Marketing Center 4     1               1              2           2         6
Marketing Center 5     1               1              2           2         6
```

The values of the Products are editable and the total gets calculated on the fly as the user inputs.

I believe this can be done with some data modelling and collection concepts. But I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the Data Source? A SQL Table? A Sharepoint List? In-app data that user creates?

Somehow you need to get a Collection of the data (ex: `colYourData`). Once you have that, use the [AddColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping) and [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-aggregates) functions to get the `Total` column.

**Something like:**

```
ClearCollect(colYourDataWithTotals, 
    AddColumns(colYourData,
        "Total",
        Sum(colYourData, product1, product2, product3, product4)
    )
)
```